# Writing a COUNTIFS with a date value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a COUNTIFS and I want to say "Count if date >= "value in cell B4"

so lets say I have something like

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!C:C,"Y",MySheet!D:D,">=B4")
```

It obviously does not recognise that it is looking for a date in cell B4 and therefore I get 0 as a result.

What syntax should I use so it recognises that I am looking for anything where the date is greater to the date in cell B4?

Comment: `">="&B4` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

`=COUNTIFS(MySheet!C:C,"Y",MySheet!D:D,">="&B4)`

### Reason

Anything you enclose in quotes ("") is taken as a string literal. So it was looking to see cells whose value was ">=B4", instead of cells whose value was greater than the value in cell B4.